# How to send SMTP message using Node.js Net (without Nodemailer)

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, smtp

First: Do not tell me to use nodemailer. I'm trying to learn about network programming and want to do this from scratch in multiple languages.

I'm trying to do a fairly simple task: send an SMTP email using TCP sockets. I have a working implementation in Python 3.6:

```py
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM
# Choose a mail server (e.g. Google mail server) and call it mailserver
mailserver = 'gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com'

# Create socket called clientSocket and establish a TCP connection with mailserver
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

def recv():
    print(clientSocket.recv(1024).decode())

# Port number may change according to the mail server
clientSocket.connect((mailserver, 25))
recv()

# Send HELO command and print server response.
clientSocket.send('HELO gmail \r\n'.encode())
recv()

# Send MAIL FROM command and print server response.
clientSocket.send('MAIL FROM: <ethan.arrowood@gmail.com>\r\n'.encode())
recv()

# Send RCPT TO command and print server response. 
clientSocket.send('RCPT TO: <ethan.arrowood@gmail.com>\r\n'.encode())
recv()

# Send DATA command and print server response. 
clientSocket.send('DATA\r\n'.encode())
recv()

# Send message data. Make sure to include header lines: From, To, Subject
clientSocket.send('FROM: <ethan.arrowood@gmail.com>\r\n'.encode())
clientSocket.send('TO: <ethan.arrowood@gmail.com>\r\n'.encode())
clientSocket.send('SUBJECT: Testing\r\n'.encode())
clientSocket.send('This is cool!\r\n'.encode())
# Message ends with a single period.
clientSocket.send('.\r\n'.encode())
recv()
# Send QUIT command and get server response
clientSocket.send('QUIT\r\n'.encode())
recv()
```

It works and outputs the following into my console:

```sh
220 mx.google.com ESMTP m30si710943qtg.40 - gsmtp

250 mx.google.com at your service

250 2.1.0 OK m30si710943qtg.40 - gsmtp

250 2.1.5 OK m30si710943qtg.40 - gsmtp

354  Go ahead m30si710943qtg.40 - gsmtp

250 2.0.0 OK 1548694151 m30si710943qtg.40 - gsmtp

221 2.0.0 closing connection m30si710943qtg.40 - gsmtp
```

I'm now trying to implement this same thing using Node.js 11.7.0 using the Net module. My code:

```
const net = require('net')

const socket = net.createConnection(25, 'gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com', () => {
  console.log('Connected!')

  socket.write('HELO gmail\r\n')

  socket.write('MAIL FROM: <ethan.arrowood@gmail.com>\r\n')

  socket.write('RCPT TO: <ethan.arrowood@gmail.com>\r\n')

  socket.write('DATA\r\n')

  socket.write('FROM: <ethan.arrowood@gmail.com>\r\n')
  socket.write('TO: <ethan.arrowood@gmail.com>\r\n')
  socket.write('SUBJECT: Testing\r\n')
  socket.write('This is cool!\r\n')
  socket.write('.\r\n')

  socket.write('QUIT\r\n')
})

socket.on('data', buff => console.log(buff.toString()))
```

This code does not work and results in the following terminal output:

```sh
Connected!
220 mx.google.com ESMTP 88si682318qte.245 - gsmtp

250 mx.google.com at your service

451 4.5.0 SMTP protocol violation, see RFC 2821 88si682318qte.245 - gsmtp
```

The 451 error does not tell anything. I do not believe the issue is with encoding as Node.js and Python3 both default to UTF-8.

I think my error has to do with how I'm calling `.write`. Like the SMTP server is receiving commands before it gets a chance to respond to a previous one. This leads me to believe there is something missing from my Node.js implementation that is provided by default in the Python3 version.

Any clues or other ideas will be much appreciated.

I expect my Node.js implementation to work just like the Python3 implementation.

Answer (score 0):

`socket.write` is an *asynchronous* function. You cannot just make a list of `socket.write`s and expect them to run sequentially.

You must use **callbacks** and write something like

```
socket.write( msg1 , () =>
    socket.write( msg2 , () => {
        [ .. ]
    } );
} );
```

Comment: You're correct; however, this callback fires once the message is sent, not when a response from the server is received. I don't know if this is a bug or intended behavior but sadly the solution isn't as simple as chaining the callbacks

Answer (score 0):

Posted this in nodejs/help and arrived at an answer
(https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1741)

It boils down to the fact that Python has blocking sockets. Calling the `recv()` method blocked the TCP stream until something was returned from the server. Node.js does not do this and their is no way to block the sockets (by design). As a result I need to utilize the `data` event to continue my socket communication.